# Finding all normal subgroups

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, normal-subgroups, symmetry

Stuck on finding the normal subgroups of the symmetry group of a cube. Trying to find 9 normal subgroups not too sure how to get the rest. Since I'm given 5 homomorphisms and I know the kernel of a homomorphism is a normal subgroup, I've identified.

1. ker($\phi$)
2. ker($det$)
3. ker($p$)
4. ker($q$)
5. ker($f$)

Now for 6, 7, 8 and 9. I know if H and K are normal subgroups, HK is.
So,

6. $HK$ where $H = \operatorname{ker}(\phi)$ and $K = \operatorname{ker}(p)$
7. $HK$ where $H = \operatorname{ker}(p)$ and $K = \operatorname{ker}(\phi)$
8. $HK$ where $H  = \operatorname{ker}(det)$ and $K = \operatorname{ker}(\phi)$
9. $HK$ where $H  = \operatorname{ker}(det)$ and $K = \operatorname{ker}(p)$

Now while this is what I got, I'm skeptical if I really approached this right. Would appreciate any assistance. Especially because I have to organize this in a lattice after and if the subgroups are wrong, all the subsequent questions are wrong.

Comment: If you know semidirect products, this group looks like $S_4 \rtimes \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a few hints:

First of all, there are two trivially normal subgroups, namely $1$ and the group $S(C)$ itself.

Second, since (as the comment indicates) $f$ is an **auto**morphism of $S(C)$, its kernel is trivial.

Third, it is a good idea to compute the orders of $\ker(\phi)$, $\ker(\det)$, $\ker(p)$ and $\ker(q)$.

Fourth: Show that $\ker(\phi)\le\ker(p)$ and that $\ker(\det)\cap\ker(p)\le\ker(q)$. What is the order of $\ker(\det)\cap\ker(p)$? Can you construct another nontrivial normal subgroup which involves $\ker(\det)\cap\ker(p)$?

And finally: What does $Z(S(C))$ look like?

Comment: The trivially normal subgroups make sense as two more examples as well as does $ker(f) = {I}$. 

Computing the orders, I get 8, 24, 24 and 24 respectively (I know ker(q) is isomorphic to ker(det) and ker($\phi$), ker(p) by computation). The center is always a normal subgroup and so Z(S(C)) is another one. Since S(C) consists of 3x3 orthogonal matrices, we know $Z(S(C)) = \{+I, -I\}$.

Comment: Confused at constructing another nontrivial normal subgroup though. My initial thought was ker(det) X ker(S(C)). Subgroups: $1, S(C), ker(\phi), ker(det), ker(p), ker(q), ker(f), Z(S(C)), ?$

Comment: Another hint: Intersections of normal subgroups are normal, too.

Comment: On that note, so I thought of that fact and considered $ker(\phi) \cap ker(det)$ as the last normal subgroup. But since there are 8 normal subgroups and 8 choose 2 possibilities of pairs, do I have to go through all 28 and find counterexamples until I lead to my own normal subgroup. Sorry for the need for added clarification but just want to make sure I got this nailed down.

Comment: Okay, first of all, the list of normal subgroups in your second comment contains only seven subgroups, since $\ker(f)=1$, so you need two additional ones. One of them is indeed $\ker(\phi)\cap\ker(det)$, which has order 4. The other one is $\ker(det)\cap\ker(p)$ which has order 12 **and is the same as** $\ker(det)\cap\ker(q)$ and $\ker(p)\cap\ker(q)$ by my fourth hint. Similarly, all other possibilities of pairs also only intersect in existing subgroups, so the total number is in fact 9.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to my other answer as well as the various comments, here's a drawing of the lattice of normal subgroups of the group $S(C))$:

[image: lattice of normal subgroups of $S(C))$]

Note that the three maximal normal subgroups intersect in a normal subgroup of order $12$ (which is, by the way, isomorphic to an $A_4$), and the intersection of that subgroup with $\ker(\phi)$ is an elementary abelian group of order $4$.