# Finding normal subgroups of the symmetry group of the cube

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, symmetry

I'm trying to find normal subgroups of the symmetry group of the cube, the one with the 48 matrices. 
Apparently there are 9 normal subgroups. 
I've found like 4, the obvious ones: the identity, the whole group itself, the kernel and the centre. (Maybe the ker(determinant) also?)
How can I go about finding the others? Any hints?
I was thinking about intersections but the order of the groups are throwing me off.

Comment: Duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2517633/finding-all-normal-subgroups?

Comment: Do not edit to remove your question.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Intersection of two normal subgroups is normal